# SQL, show List Publisher ID, Publisher Name, Title and price of the highest priced book

Tags: sql, sql-server

List Publisher ID, Publisher Name, Title and price of the highest priced book

**Table 1**

```
Books
  .ISBN
  .Title
  .PubDate
  .PubID
  .Cost
  .Retail
  .Category
```

**Table 2**

```
Publisher
  .PubId
  .Name
  .Contact
  .Phone
```

Comment: what you tried for getting this output..?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution, That would work!

```
SELECT tbl1.pubID as 'Publisher ID', 
             tbl2.Publisher as 'Publisher Name',
             tbl1.Title, 
             tbl1.Cost
FROM tables1 tbl1 
INNER JOIN tables2 tbl2 ON tbl1.pubID = tbl2.pubID
WHERE tbl1.Cost IN (SELECT MAX(tt.Cost) FROM tables1 tt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 1 tbl1.pubID as 'Publisher ID', 
             tbl2.Publisher as 'Publisher Name',
             tbl1.Title, 
             tbl1.Cost
FROM tables1 tbl1 
INNER JOIN tables2 tbl2 ON (tbl1.pubID = tbl2.pubID)
ORDER BY tbl1.cost DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl1.pubID as 'Publisher ID', tbl2.Publisher as 'Publisher Name', tbl1.Title, tbl1.Cost
FROM tables1 tbl1 INNER JOIN tables2 tbl2 ON (tbl1.pubID = tbl2.pubID)
ORDER BY tbl1.cost DESC;
```

Comment: can I have the cod to display only the record that have only highest cost

Comment: remove order by line. and add MAX after select.